# Passing pointers as function arguments in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to understand the behavior of pointers in C in context of passing them as arguments to function, so I tried messing around and making the following test case:

```
void function1(int argument)
{
     argument=4;
}
```

and

```
void function2(int* argument)
{
     *argument=5;
}
```

if I run the following statements:

```
int var1;
int* var2;
function1(var1);
function1(*var2);
function2(&var1);
function2(var2);
```

In which cases will changes made to the variables be reflected in the calling function?
I tried running the following sample code but am not able to understand output

```
#include <stdio.h>
void funone(int arg)
{
    arg=5;
}
void funtwo(int* arg)
{
    *arg=6;
}
int main(void) {
    int var1=0;
    int *var2;
    var2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *var2=0;
    funone(var1);
    printf("%d",var1);
    funone(*var2);
    printf("%d",*var2);
    funtwo(&var1);
    printf("%d",var1);
    funtwo(var2);
    printf("%d",*var2);
    return 0;
}
```

the output I'm getting is

```
0066
```

what is the implication of this output?

Comment: `function1` changes the value of the variable in the function only. And `function2` should be doing `*argument=5;` instead.

Comment: forgot the asterisk while typing, made the edits

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect your edits.

Comment: BTW `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: "What is the implication of this output?"  Really?  The implication is that function2 modifies the value pointed at by the variable so that those modifications are visible to the caller, and function1 modified the variable locally so that those modifications are irrelevant once the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for `function1` changes the value of the variable **in the function only**. So there are no repercussions of the change outside of the function.

Your `function2` works (ie, changes the values it points to) because pointers can point to variables outside of it's scope. But your first function keeps the value inside of it's scope, and once the function returns any changes are lost.

This explanation should be present in any good tutorial about pointers.

Comment: So this means that basically any function copies the values of its arguments but in case of a pointer, it is copying the address value therefore the changes are being reflected in the original function since the address is the same?

Comment: @codeln When you call a function, it will copy the values of the variable used as a paremetre and give them to the function, to be used in it's own memory space. Changes and manipulations to those variables are only visible to that function. Pointers are addresses, which allow accessing and manipulating variables declared elsewhere. So yes, your comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those examples will work as you're simply setting the value of the pointer using those functions.  Below you will find a version which achieves the behaviour you wish:

```
void function2(int* argument)
{
    *argument=5;
}
```

The reason for the asterisk before the `argument` parameter is because you are dereferencing the value of the pointer (you are getting access to it) and therefore you may, at that point change its value...

I hope this helps...